# How can Ned and Brandon Stark both be of same age?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, age

In *A Game of Thrones* it is mentioned that Brandon Stark, Ned's older brother was 20 when he died. It is also mentioned that Ned is 35 years old at the beginning of the book.

Robert took the throne 15 years ago. As the war was followed by Brandon's death, this would make Ned's age 35-15=20 when Brandon died. So this would mean that the two brothers were of same age.

How can this be? How can Ned and Brandon both be of same age?

Comment: Because human gestation is only nine months so it is possible for siblings to be born within a year of each other.

Comment: I'm the same age as my sister, I'm born in January and she in December of the same year.

Comment: The high septon [annulled it](https://youtu.be/zqj_GvdP1TE?t=1374).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**They're just one year apart.**

You can see the calculation of Ned Stark's birth at [A Wiki of Ice and Fire](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Years_after_Aegon%27s_Conquest/Calculations_Ages_(Continued)#Eddard_Stark):

> Eddard Stark is thirty-five years old in 298 AC<sup>[[11]](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Years_after_Aegon%27s_Conquest/Calculations_Ages_(Continued)#cite_note-Ragot1.7B.7B.7B3.7D.7D.7D-11)</sup>. [...] In addition, Eddard Stark is known to have been eighteen years old in 281 AC, the Year of the False Spring,<sup>[[12]](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Years_after_Aegon%27s_Conquest/Calculations_Ages_(Continued)#cite_note-Ragot58.7B.7B.7B3.7D.7D.7D-12)</sup> giving Eddard the same options as above:
>
> - seventeen turning eighteen, placing his birth in 263 AC
> - eighteen turning nineteen, placing his birth in 262 AC
>
> Eddard Stark was born one year after the birth of his brother, Brandon, who was born in 262 AC.<sup>[[14]](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Years_after_Aegon%27s_Conquest/Calculations_Ages_(Continued)#cite_note-Rtwoiafthe_targaryen_kings:_aerys_ii.7B.7B.7B3.7D.7D.7D-14)</sup> This places Eddard’s birth in 263 AC.

Brandon died in 282 AC, aged twenty. Aerys was still king at that time. Robert became king in [283 AC](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/283_AC), the same year Ned became twenty. Remember that Robert's Rebellion wasn't over in a moment: time passed between Brandon's death and Robert's victory.

Comment: Yep, beat me to it. The false assumption of Brandon dying and Robert winning his Rebellion all in practically the same moment is what throws the maths off.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot That's what also bothered me.